# Capture Certain Vertex Position

Tags: geometry-nodes

How could I capture a certain vertex position in geometry nodes?
For example, the vector position for default cube index=2 vertex.

Thank you very much!
Miguel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is with "Field at Index" node:

[image]

User Quellenform explains:
This is not necessarily "the best" way...it depends on whether you are querying the attributes within an object, or from another object. In the second case you would use Transfer Attribute (Blender <3.4) or Sample Index (Blender 3.4+).

Comment: This is not necessarily "the best" way...it depends on whether you are querying the attributes within an object, or from another object. In the second case you would use `Transfer Attribute` (Blender <3.4) or `Sample Index` (Blender 3.4+).

Comment: Thank you, Quellenform.  I would need to use it in a different independet object's geometry node. In this case, the "Sphere" object.